# Access Spring beans in GSP without controller

Tags: spring, grails, gsp

I have Spring beans defined in resources.groovy. 
And I can access them in controllers.
I also have some GSPs in views that do NOT have controllers.
I wonder how can I access beans in GSPs just like EL expressions in JSF?

For example, given a domain class like this:

```
class TestBean {  
  def name = "hello"
}
```

In spring/resources.groovy:

```
test(mydomain.TestBean) { bean -> bean.scope = 'session' }
```

In UrlMapping.groovy:

```
 '/test'(view:'/test')
```

Then, in views/test.gsp:

```
  ${test.name}
```

But the above code would throw an exception because ${test} is null. So, how can I access TestBean in GSP without controller?

I am using Grails 2.2. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also create variable with your bean as value:

```
<g:set var="testBean" bean="test"/>
```

and then use (in your *.gsp):

```
${testBean.name}
```

It's a bit quicker than creating custom `TagLib`.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a `TagLib` to to that job, and just call in your gsp.

*The TagLib*

```
class MyTagLib {
  static namespace = "my"

  def test  

  def myTag = { attrs, body ->
    out << test.name
  }

}
```

*The View*

```
<my:myTag />
```